# Allow a RewriteRule under Authenticated User in Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an Apache site where all URLs that points to a file without an extension reads as a .php file.  I put those entries in the .htaccess file, and allowed it inside the httpd.conf file.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule !\. - [H=application/x-httpd-php]
```

It works great.

Now I add authentification to the website.

```
AuthType Basic

AuthName "Restricted Content"

AuthUserFile /etc/httpd/.htpasswd

Require valid-user
```

It only works if I comment out my RewriteEngine code.

One will work without the other, but not together. I've read a bit about the REMOTE_USER variable, but failed at some attempts.

Any recommendations to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: reproduced the above config with success.

Comment: What's in the apache error log? What's in the rewrite log? http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#logging

Comment: Thank you very much to remind me to check logs.  After investigating the ssl logs indicated that I don't have rights to mod_rewrites.  I changed the AllowOverride AuthConfig to AllowOverride All and now everything works.  Thx !